# total memory of a C++ class object

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, 64-bit

Why does the following piece of code gives 24 as an answer? That is, how is the total size of the object of following class X, 24 bytes? I'm using 64-bit machine.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class X
{
    vector <bool> f;
    int b;
    public:
    X(){
        f.push_back(true);
        }
};
int main(){
    X ob;
    cout<<sizeof(ob);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would you expect? `vector` class has also internal variables to manage it's data. I don't think the standard defines the size of an empty vector so it is up to the implementation.

Comment: @AlexLop.: Note that whether a vector is empty or not has nothing to do with its `sizeof`. The former is dynamic, the latter is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is, how is the total size of the object of following class X, 24
>   bytes? I'm using 64-bit machine.

C++ makes few guarantees about type sizes and none about the memory layout of standard containers. For questions like this, it is therefore also important to state your compiler and the options with which you invoke it.

> ```
> class X
> {
>     vector <bool> f;
>     int b;
>     public:
>     X(){
>         f.push_back(true);
>         }
> };
> ```

You can look at the individual results for `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(vector<bool>)`. They will *probably* reveal the following:

- 8 bytes for `int b`.
- 16 bytes for `vector<bool> f`.

The 16 bytes for `vector<bool>` are harder to analyse. Several things *could* be stored in the object, for example:

- An instance of the `std::allocator<bool>` that you "invisibly" pass via a default argument when you construct the vector.
- A pointer to the start of the dynamically allocated memory occupied by the data to represent the vector's `bool` elements.
- A pointer to the end of that memory (for constant-time `capacity()` calls).
- A pointer to the last element inside that dynamically allocated memory (for constant-time `size()` calls).
- The current element count or the current capacity count (for constant-time `size` and `capacity()` calls).

If you want to know for sure, you can probably look into your implementation's header files to see how your compiler lays out `std::vector<bool>` in memory.

Note that the memory layout for a `std::vector<bool>` can be different from all other `std::vector`s due to [special optimisations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). For example, on my machine with MSVC 2013, compiled simply with `cl /EHsc /Za /W4 stackoverflow.cpp`, `sizeof(std::vector<bool>)` is 16 whereas `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` is 12 <sup>[*]</sup>.

Since header files internal to the implementation can be quite hard to read, an alternative way is to run your program in a debugger and inspect the object there. Here's an example screenshot from Visual Studio Express 2013:

[image: Memory layout of <code>std::vector<bool></code> and <code>std::vector<int></code> in MSVC 2013]

As you can see, the `sizeof(std::vector<bool>)` here comes from three times `sizeof(unsigned int*)` for pointers to first element, last element and capacity end in the dynamically allocated memory, plus one extra `sizeof(unsigned int)` for the element count, which is necessary due to the aforementioned special optimisation for `std::vector<bool>`, which means that calculating the difference between the pointers to first and last element may not necessarily reveal the number of elements that the vector *represents* to outside code.

`std::vector<int>` does not need that special handling, which explains why it's smaller.

The inherited `std::_Container_base0` is apparently not taken into account due to [Empty base optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo).

---

All things considered, this is all quite complicated stuff. But such is the world of standard-library implementors! Remember that all things you see inside of header files are strictly internal. You cannot, for example, suppose the existence of `std::_Container_base0` in your own code in any way. Pretend that it does not exist.

Coming back to your original question, the most important point is that your compiler may lay out a `std::vector<bool>` in any way it wants to as long as it behaves correctly to the outside world according to the C++ standard. It may also choose not to optimise `std::vector<bool>` at all. We cannot tell you much more without knowing more about your compiler. The information that it runs on a 64-bit machine is not enough.

---

<sup>[*]</sup> <sub>`std::vector<bool>` is supposed to be a space-efficient optimisation, but apparently in this implementation this only relates to space occupied by the dynamically allocated elements, not the static size of the vector itself.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

vector maintains its own internal variables for book keeping and also allocator.

Factor in the size of `int` on your machine added to the size of vector and you have the sum total.

Note:

with regards to int, size of a pointer should be 8 byte on any 64-bit C/C++ compiler, but not necessarily size of int.

you can see the internals of vector(for gcc) here for a quick lookup:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01115_source.html

Comment: What makes you think that the OP uses GCC?

Comment: what makes you think he doesnt?anyway, i have edited it

Comment: Just wanted to keep the OP from believing that C++ has kind of a "reference implementation" for container classes.