# Double free or corruption (!prev) error in my c++ destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, destructor

I have a program that does operations on a vector, not altering them but just reading once and then writing out what is required based on what is given. My program runs but I get this error at the end;

```
*** Error in './volimage: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000123c10 ***
```

I have googled, and it seems the problem is with my destructor, but I can't for the life of me find or solve it.

This is the destructor:

```
VolImage::~VolImage()
{
    std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    //deconstructing the vector of slices
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<height; j++)
        {
            delete[] slices[i][j];
        }
        delete[] slices[i]; 
    }
    slices.clear();
}
```

The vector was populated using the following:

```
std::vector<unsigned char**> slices; // data for each slice, in order

//populating vector
int i, j, k;
unsigned char ** rows = new unsigned char*[height];
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) 
    {
        unsigned char* cols = new unsigned char[width];
        string num = "%d" + j;
        fileName = baseName + num + ".raw";
        myFile.open(fileName);
        for (k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            unsigned char x;
            myFile >> x;
            cols[k] = x;
        }
        myFile.close();
        rows[i] = cols;
    }
    slices.push_back(rows);
}
```

Thanks, a hasty reply would be appreciated as i need to submit this soon

Comment: Shouldn't it be `rows[j] = cols;` instead of `rows[i] = cols;`? I.e. `j`, not `i`?

Comment: Didn't see that, thanks, but i still get the destruction problem

Comment: Why don't you just use a vector of vector of vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocated the buffer for storing pointers to pointers only once. You have to allocate ones for each rows.

Also note that the line `string num = "%d" + j;` has a big chance to cause out-of-range access because `"%d" + j` is equivalent to `&"%d"[j]` and only `0 <= j < 3` is allowed.

One more thing: `rows[i] = cols;` should be `rows[j] = cols;` as @dasblinkenlight says.

Try this:

```
//populating vector
int i, j, k;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    unsigned char ** rows = new unsigned char*[height]; // move this line
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) 
    {
        unsigned char* cols = new unsigned char[width];
        std::stringstream ss;
        string num;
        ss << j;
        ss >> num; // convert the integer stored in j to string
        fileName = baseName + num + ".raw";
        myFile.open(fileName);
        for (k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            unsigned char x;
            myFile >> x;
            cols[k] = x;
        }
        myFile.close();
        rows[j] = cols;
    }
    slices.push_back(rows);
}
```

Add `#include <sstream>` to your code if it doesn't exists to use `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. On a side note, if i wanted to count the bytes required to store the data how would i go about that? sizeOf(slices) seems to just return 24

Answer (score -1):

This is not a direct answer, I agree with @MikeCAT's answer. I want to add to the comment posted under the soln : (I dont have enough rep to post a comment directly).
 [Please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024805/c-sizeof-vector-is-24)  for why `sizeof(slices)` returns 24.

How about something like : `(width * height * sizeof(slices[0][0][0]) ) * size`, provided that `slices[0][0][0]` exists.

Comment: That's what i ended up doing, the problem is the pointers, the pointers must be included too

Comment: Please correct me, I might not understand this : If you have (height * cols_ptr_size) + (size * rows_ptr_size) that should give you the sum size of the pointers? Pointers should usually have fixed sizes (32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the architecture and I'm assuming standard examples not <32 such as 16-bit). Sorry if I'm not of more help.

Comment: Thanks :) very helpful