# C++ How to get sizeof of parent datatype?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, sizeof, volatile

1. I have struct A that holds struct B.
2. I want to have an int inside
   struct B to hold the size of struct A ().
3. However, struct B has a
   vector of an unknown size that may differ at any time.
4. The volatile
   vector will constantly change struct A's size.

How would I go about doing this without creating pointers?

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        std::vector<int> some_Vector;       // unknown size
        size_t A_size = ????;               // must always return the total size of A
    };

    B struct_B;
};
```

Comment: `without creating pointers?` std::vector is probably implemented with pointers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024805/c-sizeof-vector-is-24.

Comment: Use a function.

Comment: `sizeof(some_Vector)` will never ever change.  I suspect you have an XY problem see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Your assumption "The volatile vector will constantly change struct A's size." is wrong. Byte size of std::vector is constant, since it holds its data in dynamic memory and holds only pointer to its data start and size (or start and end)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The size of the vector itself (as given by `sizeof`) is constant, and will not be affected by how many elements it holds. Differentiate between its "logical size" and "physical size". After all, `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` must evaluate to something, and there aren't any object in the vector, there isn't a vector at all. The contents of the vector only affect the value returned by the member `std::vector::size`.
2. So the size of each structure will be something constant. You just need to obtain it after both structures are fully defined. You can accomplish that with a constructor. Instead of a default initializer.

   ```
   struct A {
       struct B {
           std::vector<int> some_Vector;      
           size_t A_size;
           B();               
       };

       B struct_B;
   };

   A::B::B() : A_size{sizeof(A)}, some_Vector{} {
   }
   ```

Though, to be frank, I see little reason why anyone would want to capture the `sizeof` a structure and hang on to it at run-time. It is, as I already said, constant.