# How does the vector::size() returns size of the vector in constant time?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I was going through this [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) and found that using vector::size() returns the size of the vector in constant time. But, I wonder how one could get the size without actually traversing the vector.

Comment: how would you get the size by traversing the vector? you need to know the size to know where to stop traversing

Comment: Potentialy relevant question: [C++ sizeof Vector is 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024805/c-sizeof-vector-is-24).

Comment: The size is stored in a member variable.

Comment: @Shawn Not necessarily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It merely keeps track of the number of elements.

If that changes then that number is updated. For example, the number of elements increases by 1 when `push_back` or `emplace_back` is called. This is one of a number of reasons why `std::vector` is not intrinsically thread-safe.

As you can imagine, this makes the implementation of `std::vector` quite fiddly - the same can be said for other C++ standard library containers too - which is a good reason for not attempting to write container classes yourself.

Comment: Why do we need to keep another variable for the number of elements if we can directly get the number of elements just by dividing capacity of the vector to the sizeof the first element?

Comment: I didn't actually *say* that - I'm a careful cat you know!

Comment: @HimanshuKumar capacity and size are different things for `std::vector`. You don't want to increase the capacity every time you add an element (because it involves reallocating the internal array and copying/moving all elements), so you grow _capacity_ by large chunks (usually exponentially) even if you are only one element too short.

Comment: @HimanshuKumar `size` and `capacity` are two different things, where `size <= capacity`. The `capacity` is the max number of elements that the currently allocated memory can hold total. The `size` is the number of actual elements that are valid within the currently allocated memory. The memory is reallocated during inserts when the new `size` would exceed the current `capacity`.

Answer (score 9):

To understand that, you need to understand how vector works.

A good mental model is:

```
class vector
{
      T *data;.              // Pointer to the first element
      size_t size;         // Number of elements in use
      size_t capacity; // Number of elements available
};
```

Whenever an element gets added:

- element gets constructed
- size gets incremented

When there is not enough capacity, we should grow the data. In short, if you look at the code of push_back, it will look like:

```
T& push_back(T const& t)
 {
      if (size == capacity)
            grow();
       constructAtEnd(t);
       ++ size;
        return back();
  }
```

In practice it's a bit more complex due to exception guarantees. However, given the above, you should be able to check your implementation of vector and recognize what's going on, for all methods.

Comment: "Most implementations" store `data+size` and `data+capacity` instead of size and capacity (that doesn't affect the mental model though).

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Perhaps, but note that *all* are required to use `std::vector<>::size_type` as the type for the element count. It wasn't the answerer's intention to go this deep; I'm sure. Have an upvote!

Comment: @Marc MSVC definitely does not. Libc++ does something similar based on 3 pointers

Comment: @Marc Type traits indeed make things more complex, I tend to ignore them if you don't use custom allocators

Comment: Personally I'd drop "(most implementations even implement it this way)" - it ruins the answer.

Comment: It should be `if (size >= capacity) grow();`

Comment: @chtz If `size > capacity` you already screwed up hard, so `size == capacity` is the only relevant case.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, yes `==` is good as well. Before my comment it said `size+1 >= capacity` which would grow prematurely.

Comment: @chtz Apologies, will check the edit history next time.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a sequence container in the STL and it has a  variable with counts the number of elements every time . When we `push_back()` any element to the `std::vector` that variable increments and when we `pop_back()` element from the `std::vector` that variable decrements.

So i think it works like this

> So std::vector::size() returns the size of that variable